# Code synchronization combining usb flash drive and Bitbucket repository

Tags: git, version-control, bitbucket

I'm new to git version-control system so I need help or advice from experts. I would like to backup and sync my 2 PCs over Bitbucket repository. One of 2 computers is without network connection. So, I have the problem.

This is equipment I plan to use for problem solving:

- PC without network (A)
- PC with network (B)
- USB flash drive (C)
- Bitbucket repository (D)

I came up with idea of git repository on USB flash drive for commiting code from A computer and later on sync those commits with B computer or with Bitbucket repository.

Is this possible? Does someone has similar setup? How to configure this?

Thanks everybody.

Answer (score 1):

You can set up [Git hooks](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks), so when you push to a remote for example you can also copy/archive/push to an alternative repository on your USB drive. Then you have to manually update your repo on PC A.

Comment: This is some kind of general answer. It falls into intermediate knowledge level.

Comment: @shx: I linked the docs you should read to advance to the *intermediate level*, I cannot write the custom scripts for you :-) Just read the chapter (something 2 pages long?) and take a look on your `.git/hooks/*.sample` scripts. Take one of them, rename to executable and modify them as needed (this is OS based, env. based, tool based -- simply use your preference).